# Passing an element of string to a function

Tags: c++, stack

When i pass an element of string 'input' to the function `output.push(input[i]);`
 , the same value doesn't get passed instead another value gets stored in `char x`

```
void stack::push(char x){
    STACK.push_back(x);
}


void string_to_stack(stack &output, string input){
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++){
        if (input[i] != ','){
            output.push(input[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

> > where 'stack' is a class as follows

```
class stack{ 
private: vector<int> STACK;
public:     stack();    
stack(vector<int>);     
void push(char); 
void pop(); 
vector<int> getter(); 
};
```

[Here's a sample of input string and STACK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMIso.png)

Comment: What is a "random value"?

Comment: @PavanChandaka
it's updated!

Comment: Can you show input and output of your execution?

Comment: do you print out after you return from `string_to_stack` ? Most probably you have the problem because `stack` is passed as value, not as a reference (use `stack&`)

Comment: but your results are totally valid? you store `int`s, so they get print out as `int`, not `char`. If you want to store `char`s, you have to change `stack` definition to `vector<char>`

Comment: `stack` type to `vector<char>`  *, he's either getting junk or a decimal char set value, but he's still not clarified what a "random value" is.

Comment: yeah, it wasn't random, a poor choice of word maybe.
And i wanted to store the char in STACK, which redefinition of vector<int> to vector<char> did.
Thanks you all!

Comment: I'd read up a little more on the fundamentals and debugging to avoid asking trivial questions. You'll be much better much faster for it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the place where you check the values in `output`, so my guess is that your code looks similar to:

```
void stack::push(char x){
    STACK.push_back(x);
}

// this one looks different in question, but void pop() makes no sense
// if top element is not available
// if you have STACK::top, substitute each pop() call below with top(), pop()
int STACK::pop() {
    int v = STACK[0];
    STACK.erase(0);
    return v;
}

// remember to use reference in the signature - otherwise original stack won't be changed
void string_to_stack(stack& output, string input){
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++){
        if (input[i] != ','){
            output.push(input[i]);
        }
    }
}

void call_site() {
    string str("abcsd");
    stack stck;

    string_to_stack(stck, str);

    while(!stck.empty())
        cout << stck.pop(); // you extract int value here
}
```

Note the change in `pop` signature - it has to return something. I chose `int`, as I suppose that's your main problem, but simply using `char` there instead of `int` might be sufficient solution (however I do not recommend it, as the compiler will complain and it's generally not a good practice to do such conversions where unnecessary)

In such case, during `cout`, you'll get numeric values of string elements (51 for '3', 43 for '+' etc. - see ASCII table). If you want to access `char`s, you either have to declare your container in `stack` as `vector<char>` instead of `vector<int>` or cast to `char` after read (e.g. `cout << static_cast<char>(stck.pop())`.

Comment: `void pop()` makes sense and indeed `std::stack` uses a void returning pop.

Comment: @A.E.Drew - you're right, of course - but `std::stack` provides `top` as well to access the element (it's not present in question `stack` definition) - I'll fix the answer to include this. Thanks for pointing it out